# How do I make Netbeans play nice with PHP files and SVN?

Tags: php, svn, netbeans

We are using netbeans as a devlopment platform for a php project and are having some small annoying issues:

1. .class will not open in netbeans since it insists that they are "binary".
2. .class and .tpl files do not play nice with subversion. Right-clicking doesn't bring up a subversion menu so I can't commit/diff/check history which is very annoying.

It feels like this could be fixed in a config file somewhere specifying which file extensions are binary etc. However, I can't find it and searching around has not helped.

Any ideas?
/K

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem is easy to solve: Just go to Tools -> Options -> Miscellaneous and then de **Files** tab. There you can add an extension and associate it with a file type.

That should solve your second problem for `.class` files as well so perhaps you need to do the same for the `.tpl` file type.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe it was that simple :)